# Download large file in an external url using javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a simple system where a user adds a url of a file he wants to download (for example an image that is on the freepik website), and then via API my PHP system generates the file to be downloaded for the user. The problem is that the API does not return a download link, but an endpoint where I should make a request passing some parameters including my API token to download. So, so that the user doesn't see this url with my API token, I used this simple code to get the API file and make it available for the user to download:

```
<?php

   $filename = $_GET['filename'];
   $url = $_GET['url'];

   header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
   header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\""); 
   readfile(urldecode($url));
```

This works for small files but when the file is too big it gives out memory limit error.

So my idea would be to rescue pieces of that file that is in the API using javascript and PHP, so that the user could download it little by little, but I don't know if that would be possible.

Is there a strategy I could use here?

@Edit

My javascript code that downloads

```
async function download(post_id) {
  var url = jQuery('input[name="url"]').val();
  var filename = jQuery('input[name="filename"]').val();
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('url', url);
  fd.append('filename', filename);
  return fetch(myAjax.ajaxurl, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: fd,
  })
    .then((result) => {
      if (!result.ok) {
        throw Error(result.statusText);
      }
      const header = result.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
      const parts = header.split(';');
      filename = parts[1].split('=')[1].replaceAll('"', '');
      return result.blob();
    })
    .then((blob) => {
      if (blob != null) {
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is very dangerous. What if the user sends `url=/path/to/secret`

Comment: `readfile()` needs a path to the file, not an URL.

Comment: @Wiimm Thanks for watching! In fact, the url is not passed via get, but generated by my system, I put it that way just to clarify it better. Thanks!

Comment: @Wiimm Somehow passing url worked fine, but when the file is too big it has some problems.

Comment: Do you get an out-of-memory error on server side or client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use streaming to download the file in chunks, This will prevent memory limit errors and allow users to download files of any size

```
<?php

$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$url = $_GET['url'];

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");

$chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunks

$ch = curl_init(urldecode($url));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, $chunkSize);

// Function to handle the streamed data
$callback = function ($ch, $str) {
    $len = strlen($str);
    echo $str;
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    return $len;
};

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, $callback);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The following code is a modification of your code, and should handle file of any sizes.

and for the JS code, you can use [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream)

here's a refactored version of your code.

```
async function download(post_id) {
  const url = jQuery('input[name="url"]').val();
  const filename = jQuery('input[name="filename"]').val();
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('url', url);
  formData.append('filename', filename);
  
  const response = await fetch(myAjax.ajaxurl, { method: 'POST', body: formData });
  if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
  
  const contentDisposition = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
  const [, name] = contentDisposition.match(/filename="(.+)"/) || [];
  const contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type');
  const contentLength = response.headers.get('Content-Length');
  const metadata = `filename:${name}\ncontent-type:${contentType}\ncontent-length:${contentLength}\n\n`;

  const stream = new ReadableStream({
    start(controller) {
      controller.enqueue(new TextEncoder().encode(metadata));
      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      function read() {
        reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
          if (done) return controller.close();
          controller.enqueue(value);
          read();
        });
      }
      read();
    }
  });

  const blob = new Blob([stream], { type: contentType });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  a.download = name;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  a.remove();
}
```

Comment: Incredible! This small code change allowed me to be able to download large files. I didn't understand 100% of the code but it gave me a good way to study streams. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AksJacoves no worries, if the answer has solved your issue, you can mark it as accepted! :) happy coding

Comment: But I found something strange. I did a test with a 685MB file and the download resulted in a 15MB file. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you check your php logs? @AksJacoves

Comment: My guess is the download may be interrupted or timed out, resulting in an incomplete file

Comment: Actually the problem is in my javascript code that downloads the file. I would probably have to modify it too. I've updated my answer with the code, do you have any suggestions of what I could modify it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253031/discussion-between-samhoque-and-aks-jacoves).

Comment: For some reason it returns a memory limit error on that line via javascript, but via PHP it goes normally: 

Line:   ob_flush();

Comment: I can't give a definite answer without actually debugging the code, if increasing the PHP memory limit is an action, you could try that. https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214893937-Increase-the-PHP-memory-limit#:~:text=Increasing%20the%20PHP%20memory%20limit,must%20create%20a%20phprc%20file.

Comment: Something I noticed recently is that when the file is too big the site simply crashes, it is not possible to interact with anything at all. Any idea why this causes this?